# Raw pg GROUP BY query in rails application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, pg

I have this very simple `SQL` query that i am trying to execute in my `rails` console.

```
SELECT name, manual_score FROM objectives GROUP BY manual_score
```

But it throws an error which is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "objectives.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I have tried by prepending table name with columns but the error remains. Any help would be appericiated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are listing a column that is not "grouped". You should add `name` to `GROUP BY` or remove it from the select.

```
SELECT name, manual_score FROM objectives GROUP BY name, manual_score
-- OR
SELECT manual_score FROM objectives GROUP BY manual_score
-- OR
SELECT COUNT(name), manual_score FROM objectives GROUP BY manual_score
```

Why do you have to add the column into your `group by` or use an aggregate function? Imagine you have the following data:

```
name       |  manual_score
one        |  1
two        |  1
three      |  2
```

Now, try to group elements by `manual_score` and think how to show `name` column that corresponds to `manual_score=1`.

Comment: This Works!! Thanks for your quick response and explanation.